# Android studio project - README / .gitignore / License files not visible

Tags: android-studio

In our new Android app project (Android studio) that we base on the example [Firebase project](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat) the files README / .gitignore / License files not visible in project navigation, although, visible when search is used.

Attaching a screenshot for example. When "Firebase Chat for Android" is searched, it's successfully found. Clicking on "Scroll to source" button has no effect, like file isn't exist.

[image]

How can it be solved?

Comment: You are not the only one. Thank you for asking this question. It saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to select `project files` in the project explorer tab to show all files. currently its filtering and reorganizing the files.

[[image: click to view animation gif]

Comment: It would be cool if we could keep the Android view style and add extra files to it. Like README.md